# WPF C# Outlook MailItem embedd multiple images

Tags: c#, wpf, mailitem

I'm using the code below to embedd an image on the body of the mailItem.

I have a doubt about "imageCid", do I need to create one for each image? How would that work?

How can I embedd multiple images? This code only attach the last image.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\chart.jpeg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
attachment = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
attachment = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
attachment = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");

string imageCid1 = "image001.jpg@123";
string imageCid2 = "image002.jpg@123";
string imageCid3 = "image003.jpg@123";
string imageCid4 = "image004.jpg@123";

attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid1);
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid2);
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid3);
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid4);

msg.HTMLBody = String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{1}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{2}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{3}\"></body>", imageCid1, imageCid2, imageCid3, imageCid4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I was overwriting the attachments.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment1 = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\chart.jpeg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment2 = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment3 = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment4 = msg.Attachments.Add(@"D:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg", OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");

string imageCid1 = "image001.jpg@123";
string imageCid2 = "image002.jpg@123";
string imageCid3 = "image003.jpg@123";
string imageCid4 = "image004.jpg@123";

attachment1.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid1);
attachment2.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid2);
attachment3.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid3);
attachment4.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid4);

msg.HTMLBody = String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{1}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{2}\"><br/><img src=\"cid:{3}\"></body>", imageCid1, imageCid2, imageCid3, imageCid4);
```